# User login null error

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.1

I am using cakephp 2.1 and I used login action in UsersController as follows.

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid email or password, try again', 'default/flash_error');
        }
    }
}
```

And the login.ctp code is as follows.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('class' => 'form')); ?>

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <?php echo $this -> Form -> text('email', array('id' => 'inputEmail', 'placeholder' => 'Email')); ?>
                    <?php echo $this -> Form -> error('email', null, array('wrap' => 'span', 'class' => 'help-block')); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <?php echo $this -> Form -> password('password', array('id' => 'inputPassword', 'placeholder' => 'Password')); ?>
                    <?php echo $this -> Form -> error('password', null, array('wrap' => 'span', 'class' => 'help-block')); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox"/>
                        Remember me </label>
                    <?php echo $this->Form->button('Sign in', array('type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn')); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

When the form get submitted with email and password, the user is not able to login so its showing an error 'Invalid email or password, try again'. Even I am passing the $this->request->data['User'] into $this->Auth->login() method and debugged $this->Session->read(Auth.User.id). Its giving me null. Please give me a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try passing `$this->request->data` into the `$this->Auth->login()` method. It's not a great way to do it (see this post: [CakePHP Auth Component Not logging in when using $this->Auth->login();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026379/cakephp-auth-component-not-logging-in-when-using-this-auth-login)), but it works for me. Have you debugged `$this->Auth->login()`?